# Subplot being offset by adding a legend to another

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to make a 2x1 subplot. The plots display correctly, though the second subplot lower than the first one (see the image below). I think I narrowed it down to this code placing the colorbar for the right plot. I attached my code for the figure and its output below..

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10), facecolor='#262626')

# Create the first subplot
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax1.set_extent([leftlon, rightlon, botlat, toplat])

# Apply features and scatter plot to the first subplot
ax1.coastlines(zorder=1)
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN, zorder=2, facecolor='#262626')
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, zorder=2, facecolor='#262626')
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, zorder=0, facecolor='#262626')
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.STATES, zorder=0, facecolor='#100c0c', edgecolor='navy')
ax1.add_feature(cfeature.STATES, zorder=4, edgecolor='navy')
ax1.scatter(dfs['fv3']['longitude'], dfs['fv3']['latitude'], zorder=5, s=200, c='red', marker='o', alpha=.8,label='FV3 HRRR')
ax1.scatter(dfs['hrrr']['longitude'], dfs['hrrr']['latitude'], zorder=5, s=70, c='skyblue', marker='o', alpha=.8,label='HRRR')
ax1.scatter(dfs['nam']['longitude'], dfs['nam']['latitude'], zorder=5, s=125, c='orange', marker='o', alpha=.8,label='NAM3k')
ax1.scatter(href_refc['longitude'], href_refc['latitude'], zorder=5, s=150, c='lime', marker='o', alpha=.8,label='HREF')
ax1.set_title('Model Reflectivity >40dBz Paintball', color='lightgray',fontsize=18)


annotation_text = x
ax1.annotate(annotation_text, xy=(fixlon, fixlat), xytext=(fixlon, fixlat), textcoords='data',
            ha='center', va='center', bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.3', edgecolor='white', facecolor='white'),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.5', edgecolor='red'),zorder= 20)


ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax2.set_extent([leftlon, rightlon, botlat, toplat])

# Apply features and scatter plot to the second subplot
ax2.coastlines(zorder=1)
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.OCEAN, zorder=2, facecolor='#262626')
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.LAKES, zorder=2, facecolor='#262626')
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE, zorder=0, facecolor='#262626')
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.STATES, zorder=0, facecolor='#100c0c', edgecolor='navy')
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.STATES, zorder=4, edgecolor='navy')

scatter2 = ax2.scatter(href_clouds['longitude'], href_clouds['latitude'],c=href_clouds['uknown'], zorder=5, s=150, cmap='plasma', marker='o',vmin=10000, vmax=80000)

ax2.set_title('HREF Echotops', color='lightgray',fontsize=18)

ax2.annotate(annotation_text, xy=(fixlon, fixlat), xytext=(fixlon, fixlat), textcoords='data',
            ha='center', va='center', bbox=dict(boxstyle='round,pad=0.3', edgecolor='white', facecolor='white'),
            arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->', connectionstyle='arc3,rad=0.5', edgecolor='red'),zorder= 20)

cbar2 = plt.colorbar(scatter2, ax=ax2, orientation='horizontal', pad=0.01, shrink=0.8)
cbar2.set_label('Unknown Value')

# Add a legend for the first subplot to the bottom with the same shrink value
ax1.legend(loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), ncol=4, fontsize='small', frameon=False, borderaxespad=0, handlelength=0.8, handletextpad=0.5, handleheight=2)
legend1 = ax1.legend(loc='lower center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1), ncol=4, fontsize='large', frameon=False, borderaxespad=0, handlelength=0.8, handletextpad=0.5, handleheight=2)

# Change the text color of the legend labels to light gray
for text in legend1.get_texts():
    text.set_color('lightgray')

# Change the color of the colorbar label to light gray
cbar2.set_label('HREF Echotops (ft)', color='lightgray')
cbar2.ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='lightgray')
plt.tight_layout()
```

[output plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sn119.png)